# Javascript: how to have a list of possible values a a variable can equal in an if construct

Tags: javascript, for-loop, or-operator

I want the value of my textarea to be a list of 1, 2, and 3s depending on the number provided in the prompt. However, it only works for the first number of each list.

```js
list = "";
onclick = function() {
  room = prompt("room");
  if (+room == (108 || 110 || 112 || 401 || 403 || 405 || 600 || 601 || 602 || 603 || 604 || 605 || 606 || 607 || 608 || 611 || 613 || 615 || 617 || 619 || 621)) {
    list += "1";
    document.getElementById("p").value = list;
  }
  if (+room == (205 || 300 || 302 || 304 || 400 || 102 || 408 || 409 || 410 || 411 || 412 || 413 || 614 || 616 || 618 || 625 || 627 || 629)) {
    list += "2";
    document.getElementById("p").value = list;
  }
  if (+room == (301 || 305 || 307 || 310 || 311 || 312 || 313 || 314 || 315 || 316 || 317 || 320 || 321 || 323 || 324 || 325 || 326 || 327 || 331 || 404 || 501 || 512)) {
    list += "3";
    document.getElementById("p").value = list;
  }
};
```

```html
<textarea id="p" /></textarea>
```

Comment: You have to compare to each number individually `+room==108 || +room==110...` I suggest you think of another way to do it however.

Comment: You can do `[108,110,112,....].includes(+room)`, all the numbers seems like a bad way to do this though...

Comment: Wrap the values in an array and use `includes` or `indexOf != -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the values in an array and then use `.indexOf()` here, like:

```
if([108,110,112,401,403,405,600,601,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,611,613,615,617,619,621].indexOf(parseInt(room)) >= 0){
    list+="1";
    document.getElementById("p").value=list;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `.indexOf(+room)` as `room` is a string.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for the hint, i missed that. corrected code.

Comment: This works. I didn't see the parseInt() so at first it didn' t work, but with parseInt(), your solution does.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code with creating an Array and using the IndexOf property,
Please refer below ,

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="p" /></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        list="";
onclick=function(){
room=prompt("room");
    var array = [108,110,112,401,403,405,600,601,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,611,613,615,617,619,621];
    if(array.indexOf(parseInt(room)) !== -1)
    {
      list+="1";
      document.getElementById("p").value=list;
    }
    var array_1 = [205,300,302,304,400,102,408,409,410,411,412,413,614,616,618,625,627,629];
    if(array_1.indexOf(parseInt(room)) !== -1)
    {
      list+="2";
      document.getElementById("p").value=list;
    }
    var array_2 = [301,305,307,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,320,321,323,324,325,326,327,331,404,501,512];
    if(array_2.indexOf(parseInt(room)) !== -1)
    {
      list+="3";
      document.getElementById("p").value=list;
    }
};

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this resolves,

Thanks

Regards